# parsererror in ajax jquery calling a webservice

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have written a webservice like below:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false, UseHttpGet = true)]
public string GetNews(int tes)
{
    return tes.ToString();
}
```

and I want to use this function in client so I wrote this lines:

```
$.ajax({
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (d) {
                    $('.widget.yellow').html(d.d);
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('.widget.yellow').html(textStatus);
                },
                data: { tes: '170' },
                url: "http://localhost:1122/Services/MyService.asmx/GetNews?format=json"
            });
```

but I get error.The textStatus is "parsererror" and xhr.statusText is "success" and xhr.status is "200" and xhr.readyState is "4".
I need some help.

Comment: You can try changing the dataType to json and also in your GetNews function change the parameter from int to string and do an explicit typecast inside the function to int.

Comment: I need to use JSONP because client and server aren't on same domain